# Can 15 puzzle really be solved by backtracking?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming, backtracking

Recently I was reading a book called "Programming Challenges". It is basically a book about algorithms. One of the chapters of the book is devoted to a backtracking technique and at the end of the chapter there are example problems from the UVA Online Judge. One of the problems is the famous [15 puzzle](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=1122).

Even though this problem is introduced in the chapter devoted to backtracking I have a serious doubts that this problem could be solved with a backtracking within the given time limit.

My question is: has anyone here managed to receive a UVA Online Judge accept with a solution which incorporates only backtracking? By this I mean you received an accept without fancy A* algorithm or using memoization from dynamic programming or some fancy solution requiring some clever recursion. I mean just backtracking. Is it possible?

Comment: I would imagine that memoization is a fairly important part of the solution...

Comment: is your question on backtracking as a viable solution to this problem or any problem in general?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I was lucky today and I found on youtube a series of lectures of the guy who wrote the book. And one of the lectures is about problems in backtracking section. [Here is the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0sxuWjANdIs). He actually shows that its a backtracking problem, just some clever pruning is needed.

Comment: The relevant bit starts at 10:30 if someone wants to skip.

Answer (score 0):

The 15 Puzzle is, like chess or a Rubik's cube, an NP-hard problem which requires searching a tree of possibilities. This kind of problem can only be solved by brute force plus pruning, which is what backtracking is. I would agree with you that it would be hard to solve this in a short time limit, because you probably have to use a heuristic of some kind to make it solvable in a reasonable amount of time. Also, you are right that some additional logic must be used because you have to remember the positions that have been visited before, otherwise you could end up searching forever, repeating the same position over and over.

Comment: "This kind of problem can only be solved by brute-force" The Wikipedia article about A* says that A* can also be used to solve the 15-puzzle.

Comment: A* is a graph search algorithm which can be used on trees because trees are a type of graph. A* is not an appropriate algorithm for 15 because there is no obvious working cost function. When A* is used on 15 without a useful cost function it is no different than backtracking.